# How to make an application that can capture all click when you press the Enter key, but in my WinForm as well?

Tags: c#, focus, event-handling, mouseclick-event

i try to develop an application who make a screenshot all mouseclick and when i hit the key "enter" for make a tutorial, but i don't see how capture this events where they are outside of my application. How i can do that ???

Comment: If you want there is my post, this is the same question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772997/how-make-application-who-can-capture-all-click-and-when-hit-enter-key-but-outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this [project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx) "Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#". I used it before and I personally always recommend it.

How to use it:

add reference tot the `Gma.UserActivityMonitor` dll to your project.

```
using Gma.UserActivityMonitor.GlobalEventProvider;

_globalEventProvider1 = new Gma.UserActivityMonitor.GlobalEventProvider();

this._globalEventProvider1.KeyDown += HookKeyDown;//to listen to key down
this._globalEventProvider1.KeyUp += HookKeyUp;//to listen to key down                
this.globalEventProvider1.MouseDown += HookMouseDown;//to listen to mouse down 
this.globalEventProvider1.MouseUp += HookMouseUp;//to listen to mouse up 

//and a lot more...
```

Comment: @tistou You are welcome :), don't forget to mark this answer as [the accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) answer if it fits your needs, so others will know that it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a look in to implementing [windows hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc188966.aspx).