# using an existing project with another project in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, editor, mouse, hook

[How to make an application that can capture all click when you press the Enter key, but in my WinForm as well?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871023/how-to-make-an-application-that-can-capture-all-click-when-you-press-the-enter-k)

This is basically a follow up question to that thread. I'm trying to make a WindowFormApp where I want the user to be able to capture four points on the screen. I want to have four textboxes and one 'capture' button. When I click the capture button, the following click's x and y coordinates will be recorded in textbox1, and so on till all 4 textboxes are full.

Each time the 'capture' button is pressed I essentially want to use the mousehook that's available here.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C

I wanted to do it as the author suggested.

> The Simple Way
>
> If you are developing a Windows Forms application and prefer drag &
>   drop programming, there is a component named GlobalEventProvider
>   inside the assembly Gma.UserActivityMonitor.dll. Just drag and drop it
>   to your form and create events using the property editor events tab.

However I cannot locate the dll to link to my form application. I'm not very familiar with the VS editor. Could someone help by pointing me in the right direction? I need help linking my WindowsFormApplication1 to this project and using this component.

Thanks!

Comment: You must download the dll from that article (links are at the top of the article; you will need an account though)

Comment: There are no dlls present in any of those 4 zipped files. Neither the src folders nor the build ones.

Comment: Well, have you tried compiling the source code?

Comment: I did try and do that, but it told me that I needed to add an executable project to the solution which "references the library project. Set the executable project as the startup project." and I didn't really know how to do that.

Comment: That happens when you try to build and run a DLL. What you want is JUST build. You can do that by hitting F6 or from the menu choose "Build" -> "Build Solution". Then go to the "Bin" folder to find the DLL.