# How to show Windows Form when user cursor is on the right side of the screen?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

i'd appreciate if someone could give me a hint :)
I have my Windows Forms `C#` app and i put the start position to the right side of the screen. Now i'd like it to appear only when the user's cursor touches right side boundary of the screen. How can i track the position of the cursor and show the form?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are probably asking about how to set up a global hook -- see : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6871142/327083

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering in terms of decomposing the question:

- How do I know where the right side of the screen is?

  - [How to retrieve the Screen Resolution from a C# winform app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402739/how-to-retrieve-the-screen-resolution-from-a-c-sharp-winform-app)
- How do I know what the position of the mouse cursor is?

  - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx

That should get you started. I'm assuming you already know how to use a Timer to repeatedly do things (such as poll for the mouse position).

Comment: But no components are visible at the time, as I understand...
But I recall Cursor.Position gets updated anytime.

Comment: I take it back - this does work in the background.  Neat.  I still like the idea of a global hook better, though, I think.  This way you respond to mouse movement rather than having to poll continuously.  Maybe it's an idealist view, but think being given data is more elegant than going to get it.

Comment: Well, it's more elegant, I do agree. But a global hook would receive every single mouse movement event, wouldn't it? In this case the OP probably doesn't need "instant" timing resolution. And last time I checked global hooks weren't exactly the easiest thing to get going.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try the both ways :)